# Neo4j: Cypher query returns wrong json result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have a problem with my cypher query.

Situation explained:
A user is able to connect to other CONTACT nodes, but he can also connect to EVENT nodes. Other users can also connect to these event nodes. We expect to retrieve the nodes we are connected to (CONTACT & EVENT) but we also need to retrieve the event nodes of the CONTACT nodes that we are connected to.

This is the graph we want to see when we retrieve the connected nodes from the bottom center CONTACT node:

[image: neo4j graph]

But we receive this json output:

```
{
  "_type": "Node",
  "_id": 1,
  "nodeType": "EVENT",
  "nodeId": 1,
  "connected_with": [
    {
      "_type": "Node",
      "_id": 0,
      "nodeType": "CONTACT",
      "nodeId": 1
    },
    {
      "_type": "Node",
      "_id": 2,
      "nodeType": "CONTACT",
      "nodeId": 2,
      "connected_with": [
        {
          "_type": "Node",
          "_id": 0,
          "nodeType": "CONTACT",
          "nodeId": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

We want to go 2 levels deep, meaning we want to see
contacts that we are connected to but also contacts we
"met" at an event hence the reason we want to go 2 levels deep.

We currently have this cypher query running but as previously mentioned, it's not working.

```
MATCH path = (n:Node {nodeId: 1})<-[:CONNECTED_WITH*]-(nodes)
WITH collect(path) as paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths) yield value as json
RETURN json
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your results seem to match what you say you want, except that it is in tree form (which you asked for).

You state that you do not "see" what you expected (presumably in the neo4j Browser). This is because the results you asked for are not plain nodes, relationships, and/or paths.

Try this, instead (note also the upper bound of `2` on the depth of the variable-length path pattern):

```
MATCH path = (n:Node {nodeId: 1})<-[:CONNECTED_WITH*..2]-(nodes)
RETURN path
```

*Aside: Having just a single node label, `Node`, with a `nodeType` property that specifies the exact "type" of node is not generally the right way to model things. It makes it harder to understand the DB, tends to complicate your code, and makes it harder to take advantage of indexing. You probably want to have separate labels (say, `Person` and `Event`). You may also want to have different relationship types as well.*

Comment: Yes, the result in the neo4j browser is correct, however the json output is not. The json output should start with the node containing the id that was supplied in the query. Then it should have connected_with nodes, and they should also contain the events that they are connected to. I should have used two different node entities to make things easier like you said! Thanks for the tip!